# Command to to restart Pantheon files manager (elemenaryOS)?

Tags: command-line, files, elementary-os, file-manager, pantheon

After editing context menu entries (by editing files in `/usr/share/contractor`) I have to restart the file manager to see the changes.

How to restart Pantheon Files with a command so that I don't have to log out and in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the command `pkill pantheon-files` in the terminal The `pkill` command sends a signal to terminate the process with name `pantheon-files`; a process is a running instance of a program. Reopen the file manager by clicking on the icon on the dock or from the application menu. By clicking on the icon, a new process is started for the program.

Answer (score 1):

For me at least for Elementary Juno the process shows as io.elementary.files - if i kill these processes then it will close.

One easy way to do this is use htop, press F4,and search for io.elementary.files, select a process then F9 to kill.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera. On this version, the default files manager appears to be io.elementary.files, so to kill it, do `pkill -f io.elementary.files`.